# Integration between Nutch 1.11(1.x) and Solr 5.3.1(5.x)

Tags: solr, nutch, solr5

I just started using **Nutch 1.11** and **Solr 5.3.1**.

I want to **crawl data with Nutch**, then **index and prepare for searching with Solr**.

I know how to crawl data from web using `Nutch`'s `bin/crawl` command, and successfully got much data from a website in my local.

I also started a new `Solr` server in local with below command under `Solr` root folder,

```
bin/solr start
```

And started the example `files` core under the example folder with below command:

```
bin/solr create -c files -d example/files/conf
```

And I can login below admin url and manage the `files` core,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/files
```

So I believe I started the `Solr` correctly, and started to post the `Nutch` data into `Solr` with `Nutch`'s `bin/nutch index` command:

```
bin/nutch index crawl/crawldb \
-linkdb crawl/linkdb \
-params solr.server.url=127.0.0.1:8983/solr/files \
-dir crawl/segments
```

Hoping with `Solr5`'s new **Auto Schema** feature, I can put myself restful, however, I got below error(copy from log file):

```
WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
INFO  segment.SegmentChecker - Segment dir is complete: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s1.
INFO  segment.SegmentChecker - Segment dir is complete: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s2.
INFO  segment.SegmentChecker - Segment dir is complete: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s3.
INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: starting at 2015-12-14 15:21:39
INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: URL filtering: false
INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: URL normalizing: false
INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Active IndexWriters :
SolrIndexWriter
    solr.server.type : Type of SolrServer to communicate with (default 'http' however options include 'cloud', 'lb' and 'concurrent')
    solr.server.url : URL of the Solr instance (mandatory)
    solr.zookeeper.url : URL of the Zookeeper URL (mandatory if 'cloud' value for solr.server.type)
    solr.loadbalance.urls : Comma-separated string of Solr server strings to be used (madatory if 'lb' value for solr.server.type)
    solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
    solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to Solr (default 1000)
    solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth.username : username for authentication
    solr.auth.password : password for authentication


INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: crawldb: crawl/crawldb
INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s1
INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s2
INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: file:/user/nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/s3
WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/staging/user117437667/.staging/job_local117437667_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/staging/user117437667/.staging/job_local117437667_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/localRunner/user/job_local117437667_0001/job_local117437667_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
WARN  conf.Configuration - file:/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/localRunner/user/job_local117437667_0001/job_local117437667_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off
INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250 documents
WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local117437667_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:512)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.write(SolrIndexWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.write(IndexWriters.java:85)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:50)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:356)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:145)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:231)
```

I remember this

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.
```

Is something related to the `Solr` url, but I double check with the url I used `127.0.0.1:8983/solr/files`, I think it is correct.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I search on the web and in here, got nothing useful.

Note: I also tried the way which disabled `Solr5`'s **Auto Schema** feature in `examples/files/conf/solrconfig.xml` and replaced `examples/files/conf/managed-schema.xml` with `Nutch`'s `conf/schema.xml`, still hit the same error.

**Update**: After trying the **DEPRECATED** command `bin/nutch solrindex`(Thanks to `Thangaperumal`), the previous error is gone but hit another error:

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/files crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/s1
```

Error message:

```
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 250 documents
WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1306504137_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Unable to invoke function processAdd in script: update-script.js: Can't unambiguously select between fixed arity signatures [(java.lang.String, java.io.Reader), (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] of the method org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain.tokenStream for argument types [java.lang.String, null]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Unable to invoke function processAdd in script: update-script.js: Can't unambiguously select between fixed arity signatures [(java.lang.String, java.io.Reader), (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] of the method org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain.tokenStream for argument types [java.lang.String, null]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:552)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.write(SolrIndexWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.write(IndexWriters.java:85)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:50)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:422)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:356)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:145)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:231)
```

Comment: Does Nutch need hadoop running ? I am not sure about this.

Comment: I'm having this problem also, with Solr 5.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, Try this statement to integrate solr and nutch

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/
```

Comment: Hint by the `bin/nutch` help message, is it not the `solrindex` command ##DEPRECATED##? I also tried you way with some edit to the url, there is progress! let me update the question.

Comment: I guess your command will also work if you give as  -params  solr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr

Comment: As far as  i remember, the core has to be specified in one of the nutch conf file (something like schema.xml). so you don't need to specify core in solr.server.url

Comment: Well, funny fact is if I only used the url without core name, then it would hit the same error like previously did, and then I added the core name, it comes up a new error, do you know the second kind of error? I update it in the question.

Comment: This error is because of the field list mismatch (misspelled fields/data type mismatch/missed fields) between your nutch data fields and solr. you have to cross-check fields in update-script.js

Comment: Well...I did not specify any schema info in Solr, as I am using the auto schema feature of Solr5, should I use the nutch provided schema xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97849/discussion-between-resec-and-thangaperumal).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the Solr URL using:

```
-D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/files
```

instead of the `-params` approach? At least this is the right syntax for the `crawl` script. And since both invoke an underline java class to do the work should work.

```
bin/nutch index crawl/crawldb \
-linkdb crawl/linkdb \
-D solr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/files \
-dir crawl/segments
```

Comment: Tried your way, hit `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 15: solr.server.url=http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/files`, I am following the `bin/nutch index` help message to call.